# How to fix `--os-auth-token: expected one argument` glance error?

Tags: linux, authentication, arguments, openstack

My command:

```
$ glance --os-auth-token --os-image-url http://google.com:9292 image-create --name cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-uec-kernel --public --container-format aki --disk-format aki
```

Output:

```
Usage: 
glance [--version] [-d] [-v] [-k] [--cert-file CERT_FILE] [--key-file KEY_FILE] [--os-cacert <ca-certificate-file>] [--ca-file OS_CACERT] [--timeout TIMEOUT] [--no-ssl-compression]
glance: error: argument --os-auth-token: expected one argument
```

Comment: this is because you try to run openstack in your vm that only have RAM 1G or less so your mysql cannot authorize your call


simply edit your /etc/mysql/my.cnf 

add this line under [myqsld]

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8M


please upgrade your RAM so your openstack can run smooth

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid auth token for the glance-api RESTful API.

You can get that token from keystone, or keep os_username, os_password, os_auth_url, and tenant_name env variables set.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you're trying to run openstack in your VM that only have RAM 1G or less.

So your MySQL cannot authorize your call simply edit your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` add this line under:

```
[myqsld]
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8M
```

Or please upgrade your RAM so your openstack can run smooth.